# google map adjust with full screen not working

Tags: css, google-maps

the below code working fine.

```
<div id="map_wrapper">
   <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>
<style>
  #map_wrapper {
    height: 750px;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

while adjusting the `#map_wrapper` content from `height: 750px` to `height: 100%` it got blank.

I tried `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a size of the parent container (100% of 0 is 0).

[Mike Williams' explanation from his Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

```
#map_wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
html, body, #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fc3jmxbz/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
#map_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_wrapper">
  <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>
```